# If $X \sim \exp(3)$ what is the PDF of $Y=e^{2X}$?

Tags: probability

If $X \sim \exp(3)$ and let $Y = e^{2X}$ what is the PDF of $Y$? 
$$
\begin{align}
F_Y(y)& = P(Y\leq y) \\
& = P(e^{2X} \leq y) \\
&=P(X \leq \ln(\sqrt{y}))
\end{align}
$$
Then you need your CDF will look like
$$
\begin{align}
P(X \leq \ln(\sqrt{y})) &= \int_0^{\ln(\sqrt{y})}3e^{-3x}dx \\
\end{align}
$$
Using the fundamental theorem of calculus we get that the PDF of Y will be 
$$
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= 3(e^{-3ln(\sqrt{y})}-1) \\
& =3(y^{-3/2}-1) \quad y>1 
\end{align}
$$

The PDF doesnt integrate to 1 on it's support so there has to be a mistake however I don't where exactly please help me find it.

Comment: Note: The fundamental theroem of calculus says that for functions $f, g$ and constant $c$: $$\displaystyle\dfrac{\mathsf d~~}{\mathsf d y}\int_c^{g(y)}f(x)~\mathsf d x = g'(y)~f(g(y))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using the fundamental theorem of calculus we get that the PDF of Y will be

$$\require{enclose}\begin{split}f_Y(y) &= \mathbf 1_{y\in[1;\infty)}\cdot \dfrac{\mathsf d ~~}{\mathsf d y}\int_0^{\ln\surd y} 3 e^{-3x}\mathsf d x\\ & = \mathbf 1_{y\in[1;\infty)}\cdot\enclose{circle}[color:red]{\color{black}{\dfrac {\mathsf d \ln\surd y}{\mathsf d y}}}\cdot 3e^{-3\ln\surd y}\\ & = \mathbf 1_{y\in[1;\infty)}\cdot\dfrac 1{2y}\cdot 3(\surd y)^{-3}\\ &=\tfrac 32 y^{-5/2}~\mathbf 1_{y\in[1;\infty)}\end{split}$$

Answer (score 0):

You slipped a sign and forgot to differentiate. You have
$$F_Y(y) = 1 - y^{-3/2},\qquad y > 1.$$ Now differentiate to get
$$f_Y(y) = 3/2 y^{-5/2}, \qquad y > 1.$$
This last item integrates to 1.

Comment: Why don't you use the fundamental theorem of calculus once you differentiate?

Comment: @Anonymous Well, this way seems easier and less error prone.